# Okta Expression Language statement for retreiving part of the group name

Tags: okta, okta-api, identity-management

I have few Okta groups with naming convention like this: app-appname-team-accessLevel, app-appname- is a constant part and team-accessLevel changes based on user. Example: app-appname-security-read, app-appname-security-admin etc. I have to send custom parameters from Okta to this App. I need two parameters, team and accessLevel where both of them would be a part of the group name pulled out using Okta Expression language.

I've tried to create customized Okta Expressions to pull proper part of the group name out: `Arrays.flatten(substringBefore(substringAfter(substringAfter("app-appname-team-accessLevel", "-"), "-"), "-"))`
This line successfully pulling out "team" from the string, but I'm unable to replace this hard coded string with some expression that would pull out an actual groups assigned to user. The other issue I'm facing is that user can be a part of multiple groups, so I've made this attribute string array and in the perfect scenario, if user is a part of groups app-appname-security-read and app-appname-hr-admin, attribute should be ["security","hr"]. I've tried to combine my line with this line from Okta docs: `getFilteredGroups({"00gml2xHE3RYRx7cM0g3"}, "group.name", 40)`, but I'm not sure if I can filter out based on something other than group id. Is there some way to create an Okta Expression Language which would handle this task or there is some more efficient approach I can use in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like too complicated for expression language. Have you looked into a possibility to create a workflow triggered off of a group assignment, which will parse group name assigned and populate a user attribute based on the third part of the group name (divided by "-")?

I believe Okta offers several workflows free of charge, but better to check with the Support.